# Callback using no parameters and this.push

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been going through nodeschool.io's tutorials and was stumped on a specific problem involving streams. This was the given solution.

I'm primarily confused about the upper variable and why I need to call this.push. Can't I just pass the data variable through the callback function (next()) ?

A line by line explanation of what is going on here would be most appreciated.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var through2 = require('through2');

var upper = through2(function(data, _, next) {
   data = data.toString().toUpperCase();
   this.push(data);
   next();
});

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
   if (req.method == 'POST') {
      req.pipe(upper).pipe(res);
   }
}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats just how the API for the through2 function works. From the [documentation](https://github.com/rvagg/through2#transformfunction)

> The transformFunction must have the following signature: function (chunk, encoding, callback) {}. A minimal implementation should call the callback function to indicate that the transformation is done, even if that transformation means discarding the chunk.
>
> To queue a new chunk, call this.push(chunk)—this can be called as many times as required before the callback() if you have multiple pieces to send on.

So apparently the reason for the this.push is to make it easy to deal with the case where you need to push lots of chunks.

```
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
     this.push( /**/ )
}
```

That said, according to the documentation you can also pass chunks to the callback like you want:

> Alternatively, you may use callback(err, chunk) as shorthand for emitting a single chunk or an error.

I couldn't test but my guess it that you want something similar to

```
var upper = through2(function(data, _, next) {
   data = data.toString().toUpperCase();
   next(null, data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @hugomg ! I'm also having trouble understanding the
req.pipe(upper).pipe(res) line. To my understanding the request sends its information to upper to be transformed, but when it returns via the callback, is the second pipe called on the return value?

Comment: I don't actually know nodejs enough to answer that question. Maybe you should create a new question just for that.